# Android: Section Page Adapter not being assigned

Tags: android, debugging

I have the following code:

```
package com.example.me.echoboard;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "Message Board");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "Statistics");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab3Fragment(), "My Notes");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I somehow broke my project. The error debugged is that on the last line, I'm setting viewPager to adapter which supposedly is null.

The IDE does confirm that. When hovering over mSectionsPageAdapter in `private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;`, I'm told that it is assigned but never accessed (which then would make sense as to why it is null). However this is clearly incorrect, it is being assigned `mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());`

I can't see where the issue is. Again, the structure of the code is fine, it was working flawlessly until I started finicking with some data visualization tools, following which the error message appeared.

Does anyone have an idea where to start looking?

Thanks!

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.me.echoboard, PID: 16132
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.me.echoboard/com.example.me.echoboard.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.me.echoboard.MainActivity.setupViewPager(MainActivity.java:31)
                      at com.example.me.echoboard.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're using `mSectionsPageAdapter` in that `setupViewPager` method. You're creating a new adapter and using that instead. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Chris That wouldn't be the issue. I won't make you watch the 15 minutes of this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNpWGI_hGGg) but I followed this and it was working well following the same structure as he points out.

Comment: Gotcha, could you post the text of the error message? Especially the stack trace if you have one?

Comment: @Chris Sure thing, please see in the comments

Comment: Ahh, I think the issue is with ViewPager. I'm sure the adapter exists, but my guess is that `findViewById(R.id.container)` returns null. Can you verify that the View Pager's id is indeed `id/container`?

Comment: In his video, it also seems that his mSectionsPageAdapter isn't recognized by the IDE as assigned, so that isn't the issue. I've never had to deal with this. I don't know how to debug without having a clue as to where I should look, especially given that I have quite a few files.

Comment: @Chris Will do Chris, one second.

Comment: You're missing a force cast when assigning 'mViewPager'. Also what the ide points out is correct, you're assigning mSectionsPager but never using it. You can access member variables from instance methods you know, instead of passing them as parameters to the methods. It's not advisable

Comment: @Chris Right on with the container not being correctly declared in the XML. Appreciate it! If you care about karma, post a quick answer, i'll be happy to mark it as accepted. Thanks regardless!!

Comment: Sweet, I'll write that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue of an unused assignment to `mSectionsPageAdapter`, while true, is a red herring. Based on the exception text you posted, a `NullPointerException` is being thrown during the assignment of that adapter to the ViewPager, which implies that the ViewPager's reference is null.

That null reference has its origins on the line `mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);`, so make sure in your layout file that the id of that view pager is indeed `id/container`.